# Wordpress admin panel error?

Tags: php, wordpress

While accessing the admin panel of my site http://freepokemmorpg.com/wp-admin/ te following error appears

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/freepoke/public_html/wp-content/themes/hanami/functions.php:9) in /home/freepoke/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 899
```

Comment: remove all spaces from top will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dear remove all space into that file and functions.php file.

and remove all black line.

then check. this is working.

Comment: No dear, I have removed all white spaces but still not working!!

Comment: ok remove all white space into themes/yourtheme/functions.php file

Comment: Ok great, removing the spaces from functions.php and re-organizing the code block did the trick!!